# React Native Navigation Without navigation Prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

[React Native Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/) say that we can use React Navigation without `navigation` prop. I use it when I click on a notification and redirect to correct screen:

`navigationRef.current?.navigate(routes.ROUTE_TO_SCREEN);`

However I have cases where I need to navigate more than once (e.g. go to navigator first, then to screen). I thought it would work this way:

```
navigationRef.current?.navigate(routes.ROUTE_TO_NAVIGATOR);
navigationRef.current?.navigate(routes.ROUTE_TO_SCREEN_INSIDE_NAVIGATOR);
```

and it works on screen but I get an error first on the console saying:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ROUTE_TO_SCREEN_INSIDE_NAVIGATOR"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'route_to_screen_inside_navigator'?
```

Even though it works, I think I am doing something wrong. Should I await the `navigation.navigate` somehow to make the error go away or is there another way?

I have also checked [navigation in nested navigator docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator), but didn't quite get how to navigate using `params` in `navigate` function.

Edit: After reviewing the link above I have found a solution to one-layer navigator, such as:

```
navigationRef.current?.navigate(routes.ROUTE_TO_NAVIGATOR, 
    { screen: "route_to_screen_inside_navigator",
});
```

But that works only for one nested navigator. What if I would want to redirect twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep passing params.screen into the `navigate` call to continually navigate into deeply nested screens.

[Reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#passing-params-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator)